# how to access class of this?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

basically i have

```
$("msgbox .content").html("FOO");
```

but i have made a plugin and need to replace msgbox with $(this), so how to i select a class of $(this)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly:

```
$(".content", this).html(...);
$(this).find(".content").html(...);
```

Both are the same thing.